# Docker - Instalação do Jenkins - (Comando Docker:dind)

Tags: docker, jenkins

Olá, pessoal!
Estou fazendo a instalação da imagem do Jenkins no meu Docker seguinte este tutorial no próprio site do Jenkins : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#on-windows

Estou verificando cada um dos comandos que estou executados para criação do container e fiquei com uma dúvida neste passo:
[image: passo 4 instalação do jenkins no docker]

O que significa o último comando docker:dind?
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Velho, coloca o código em texto, Fica melhor para quem for analisar e te responder.

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente o último componente de um comando de docker run, build e outros é a imagem que você está usando pra executar o comando. No caso da sua pergunta, docker:dind é a imagem que vai ser usada como base para todos os comandos anteriores. A imagem no caso é [essa](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker).